# Reading commit for specific file with isomorphic-git

Tags: javascript, isomorphic-git

I want to read the commit history of specific files. What I have tried so far:

```
git.log({fs, dir: '.', filepath: 'path/to/file', depth: 2})
```

But I get:

```
<git.log>: Could not find file or directory found at "5cd2fc6d4023ff3c104801498e4f54a3cbae4c6b:path/to/file
```

If I leave out the `filepath` I do get the last commits. But I need the date specific files have been changed.
I'm using the latest version 1.25.6. The git working directory is clean.

Comment: According to [isomorphic-git doc](https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/log), try the option `force: true`, which has the effect that `do not throw error if filepath is not exist (works only for a single file). defaults to false`.

Comment: Did that (should have mentioned). But then I get an empty array of commits for every file.

Comment: With git commands, it would be `git log -2 -- path/to/file` instead of `git log -2 
 path/to/file`. The standalone `--` is important. If `git.log` cannot handle with this case, it seems a bug.